# How to resize windows beyond monitor size using CLI?

Tags: linux, xdotool

I have two monitors and I'd like to programmatically resize clicked window beyond my first monitor size. I want -39,-138 coordinates and 2355x1202 window size. My first monitor is 1680x1050, the other one is 1920x1080. I have this xdotool script:

```bash
wid=$(xdotool selectwindow)
xdotool windowmove $wid -39 -138
xdotool windowsize $wid 2355 1202
```

But the problem with xdotool is it doesn't move/resize windows beyond current monitor size, so above script's result is the same as just maximize (moves to 0,0 and resizes to 1680x1050). How do I move/resize my windows beyond monitor size using CLI?

I also tried:

- `wmctrl -r :SELECT: -e 0,-39,-138,2355,1202` - doesn't do anything for me

I use:

- Linux Manjaro KDE (x11)

Thank you.